# How can I create this ui in Flutter...?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to code [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl9ci.jpg)  player card  in flutter.
need to design this ,I can create this as a card but the curves are difficult.

sharing code below,
I can create rows and columns but the curves are difficult.please help

```
class PLayerCard extends StatefulWidget {
PLayerCard(this.image);
String image;

@override
_PLayerCardState createState() => _PLayerCardState();
}

class _PLayerCardState extends State<PLayerCard> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * .4,
  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * .4,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Container(
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * .2,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Column(
                children: [Text("Points"), Text("305")],
              )),
          Container(
            child: widget.image != null
                ? Image(
                    height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * .2,
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * .29,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      widget.image,
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)
                : Image(image: AssetImage('assets/user-avatar.png')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.green[800],
      ),
      Container(
        height: 50,
        color: Colors.green,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like a stack and a row of pictures. I could interact with them with an inkwell

Comment: I think the easiest way is get the card as asset

I also had to do something similar and the easiest thing was to put the asset as the background and just build the content

Comment: @JonathanIxcayau but i need help in curves.

Comment: You can use a flutter canvas [read this](https://medium.com/flutteropen/canvas-tutorial-01-how-to-use-the-canvas-in-the-flutter-8aade29ddc9)
But i really recomend use card as background png

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much ..Got the shape I needed.You save my day